# Understanding how Ajax success callback updates state in this ReactJS example

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am working thought the Reactjs [Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#adding-new-comments). I am trying to understand how the CommentForm component submits (or updates the server) with the data it has collected via passing it up to the CommentBox.

Here are the two components that work for reference:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value.trim();
    var text = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value = '';
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value = '';
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});





var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My source of confusion comes from `handleCommentSubmit` in the CommentBox component, specifically the Ajax success callback.

Since we set `data: comment`, `data` is now merely the comment the form collected. But on success we take data and do `this.setState({data: data});`. Wouldn't that be setting the state to only one comment (the one we collected in the form?). Wouldn't we need to pull from the server to get all of the data, including the POST we just made with something like `loadCommentsFromServer`? How does this work?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since we set data: comment, data is now merely the comment the form
>   collected. But on success we take data and do this.setState({data:
>   data});. Wouldn't that be setting the state to only one comment (the
>   one we collected in the form?).

No, in the example, the `comment` passed in to the function is setting the `data` property for the ajax *request*.  The `data` parameter in the `success` callback is the data from the ajax *response*.

So, here they are setting the `data` state property to whatever the server responds with.  I think the example assumes that the server is reflecting the same comment, but this allows the server to *save* the comment during the HTTP call.